# Call sendEmail method inside a loop?

Tags: apex, email, governorlimits, bestpractice, singleemailmessage

Is it advisable to use `sendEmail()` method inside a for loop? Does it perform any `DML Operations` that could probably hit my `SOQL` limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a maximum number of email invocations as well, and it is actually much lower, **`10`**. So no, you should not call it in a loop if you can avoid it.

See [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm):

> Total number of sendEmail methods allowed: 10

See also [Outbound Email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm):

> Note the following:
>
> - The email is not sent until the Apex transaction is committed.
> - The email address of the user calling the `sendEmail` method is inserted in the `From Address` field of the email header. All email that is returned, bounced, or received out-of-office replies goes to the user calling the method.
> - Maximum of 10 `sendEmail` methods per transaction. Use the [Limits methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_methods_system_limits) to verify the number of sendEmail methods in a transaction.
> - Single email messages sent with the `sendEmail` method count against the sending organization's daily single email limit. When this limit is reached, calls to the `sendEmail` method using `SingleEmailMessage` are rejected, and the user receives a `SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` error code. However, single emails sent through the application are allowed.
> - Mass email messages sent with the `sendEmail` method count against the sending organization's daily mass email limit. When this limit is reached, calls to the `sendEmail` method using `MassEmailMessage` are rejected, and the user receives a `MASS_MAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` error code.
> - Any error returned in the `SendEmailResult` object indicates that no email was sent.

---

There used to be a limit on the number of messages you could send *per* invocation (100), so you would have to batch them into multiple `sendEmail` calls if you went over that number. It seems to have been lifted recently, however. See: [Emails Per Invocation Still Capped at 100?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137203/emails-per-invocation-still-capped-at-100)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) I will be exploring MassEmailMessage option for my use case now.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, since it was incorrect. You may want to simply state that you can send them all at the end now.