# Maximum Number of Email Invocations Exceeded

Tags: apex, email, batch, governorlimits, schedulebatch

I am getting an error of too many email invocations in my batch class.Code is as follows :-

```
global with sharing class PAM_SendFRBNotificationBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{

     global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
   {
    Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMap = Schema.SObjectType.Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    Id rtLeadID =  rtMap.get('LO FRB').getRecordTypeId();
    string query= 'Select id,Status__c,RecordtypeId,Organization_Name__c,OwnerId,Owner.Name,Organization_Name__r.Number_of_Exception__c,Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c,Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c,Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c FROM Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c WHERE Status__c != \'Closed\' AND RecordtypeId =: rtLeadID';
    system.debug('query'+query); 
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
   }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c[] pamList)
   {
     //for(Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c pam : pamList)  
     //{        
        Set<Id> OwnerIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c pam : pamList)
        {
          OwnerIds.add(pam.OwnerId);
        }      
        system.debug('*******OwnerIds'+OwnerIds);  

    for(Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c pam1 : pamList)
     {  
        for(String ownerId : OwnerIds)
        {
            system.debug('*******OwnerIds1'+OwnerIds);  
                if(Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_Exception__c)!= 0 || Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c)!= 0 
             || Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c)!= 0 || Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c)!= 0)
             {
                system.debug('Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_Exception__c)*******'+Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_Exception__c));
                system.debug('Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c)*******'+Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c));
                system.debug('Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c)*******'+Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c));
                system.debug('Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c)*******'+Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c));


                     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                String body =   'Hello  '+pam1.Owner.Name+'\n'+'\n'+'Below are links to the firm reported balance exception lists. Click on each link or log into'
                                         +'\n'+'Salesforce accessing the Process Adherence Monitoring Object list views to get the list of'
                                         +'\n'+'accounts for each timeframe bucket.'+
                                         +'\n'+'\n'+'Please review each exception and submit a new record 42 with corrections.'+'\n'+'\n'+'0-3 Days (Green – New Exception)     '+Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_Exception__c)
                                         +'\n'+'\n'+ '4-6 Days (Yellow – Outside Correction Timeframe)     '+   Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_4_6_bucket__c)
                                         +'\n'+'\n'+'7-10 Days (Orange – Approaching Critical Timeframe)     '+   Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_7_10_bucket__c)
                                         +'\n'+'\n'+'11-19 Days (Red – Immediate Correction Required)     '+   Integer.valueOf(pam1.Organization_Name__r.Number_of_exceptions_under_11_19_bucket__c)
                                         +'\n'+'\n'+'Please reach out to Lo-Operational@mcmcg.com with any questions you may have.'
                                         +'\n'+'\n'+'Thanks'
                                         +'\n'+'\n'+'FRB';

                        mail.setSubject('Firm Reported Balance Exceptions ');
                        mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(pam1.OwnerId);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            }  
          }
        }
     /* 
        */     
       //} 
   }   
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {}
}
```

Comment: Problem is that there are no more than 10 sendEmail methods allowed per execution context. What to do -- sendEmail once per batch. (create emails in loop, add them into list and send an email in the end).

Answer (score 6):

The easiest fix for this would be to declare a `List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>` outside your `for` loops. Inside your iterations, rather than calling `Messaging.sendEmail()` each turn, you'd add the individual `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` to the list, calling `Messaging.sendEmail()` on the collection itself.

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

for ([...]) {
    for ([...]) {
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setToAddresses(new String {
            'foo@bar.com'
        })
        message.setHtmlBody([...]);
        // Add the rest...

        lstMails.add(message);
    }
}

Messaging.sendEmail(lstMails);
```

This is pretty much the same practice as you'd use with DML.

Comment: Yep. Pretty much the same, except even more stringent! +1

Comment: @AdrianLarson I guess as a footnote it's worth noting that it's more stringent for a reason. Correct me if I'm wrong here but Salesforce in and of itself isn't a marketing platform per se, hence the tight limits, rather you'd need to look at Pardot or ExactTarget depending on the use case for that. If you're less of a "purist", there's other options too of course that can integrate with Salesforce (MailChimp, CommunicatorCorp, Mailgun et al...)

Comment: Yeah but they did [remove the limit on the number of addresses you can blast in one go](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137203/emails-per-invocation-still-capped-at-100). So it's not like that really caps you too much.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Now that is interesting! I'm suprised actually that SF would relax this given how much they invested in mass-marketing, I'd have expected them to capitalise on it more.

Answer (score 2):

To build up on what @manchesterdunited said:

- [Only ten sendMail execs per context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), try to sendMail outside your loops.
- [Limited amount of e-mail addreses reachable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm) depending on your edition.