# Passing List of emails in Chunk as Toaddress in SingleEmail message

Tags: singleemailmessage

Can you Try to help me how to pass list of Toaddress in Single email messages as a chunck as per the salesforce documentation we can set 100 Toaddress but in my requirement i have more than 300 mails how to split in to 100 each and pass the list to Toaddress() Property i written the below logic can u help us how to pass the list one by one.
code snippet:

```
list<Account> finalAccount=[Select account.owner.email from account];
integer counter=0;
list<String> FirstsetofList=new list<String>();
list<String> SecondsetofList=new list<String>();
list<String> Thirdsetoflist=new list<String>();
Map<id,list<String>> FirstMaplist=new Map<id,list<String>>();
Map<id,list<String>> SecondMaplist=new Map<id,list<String>>();
Map<id,list<String>> ThirdMaplist=new Map<id,list<String>>();

for(Account Thisaccount :finalAccount){
    if(counter<10){
        FirstsetofList.add(Thisaccount.owner.email);
        FirstMaplist.put(Thisaccount.id,FirstsetofList);
        counter++;
   }

    else if(counter>9 && counter<20 ) {
        SecondsetofList.add(Thisaccount.owner.email);
SecondMaplist.put(Thisaccount.id,SecondsetofList);
        counter++;
    }
    else{
       Thirdsetoflist.add(Thisaccount.owner.email); 
ThirdMaplist.put(Thisaccount.id,Thirdsetoflist);
    }
  }

List<String> FirstsetToadd=new list<String>();
List<String> SecondsetToadd=new list<String>();
List<String> ThirdsetToadd=new list<String>();

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage Singlemail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
for (Id keys : FirstMaplist.keySet()) {
    FirstsetToadd= FirstMaplist.get(keys);
  }
for (Id keys : SecondMaplist.keySet()) {
    SecondsetToadd= SecondMaplist.get(keys);
  }
for (Id keys : ThirdMaplist.keySet()) {
    ThirdsetToadd= ThirdMaplist.get(keys);
  }

Singlemail.setToAddresses(FirstsetToadd); 
 Singlemail.setSubject('Opt Out Test Message');
Singlemail.setplainTextBody('This is the message body.');
mails.add(Singlemail);

 Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/192704), you can easily create a list of at least 10,000 SingleEmailMessage items, with one email each, and send them all at once.

Please note that you should be using setTargetObjectId to send the emails, otherwise you will quickly exhaust your daily limits for emails (emailing users do not count towards the limit).

Comment: but for this TargetObjectID we are passing ContactID have different functionality running on that Property ..i dont know how to chunk now

Comment: @Jeniffer you can still set setTargetObjectId to a contact Id if you prefer, but those are limited to a few thousand a day. I think my main point is that Messaging.sendEmail can accept a list of thousands of emails without a problem. This is far easier than trying to specify multiple emails per email.

Comment: But the salesforce Documents says.setToAddresses(toAddresses)
Optional. A list of email addresses or object IDs of the contacts, leads, and users you’re sending the email to. The maximum number of email addresses allowed is 100.

Comment: i have two scinerios for Toaddress() they are not sending email template as an attachment and for TargetObjectID we are sending attachment only for contactID.So i dont have options to merge both contactIDs and USerids

Comment: @Jeniffer Yes, it's 100 *per email*. You can send up to 10,000 emails with 100 email addresses each.

Comment: Can i know the logic please

Comment: @Jeniffer Example already in the previous answer. Go ahead and take a look at it.