# Which limits are likely to affect a bulk SingleEmailMessage transaction?

Tags: governorlimits

We wrote a custom campaign function that sends individualized emails in one large SingleEmailMessage list. I'm wondering how to estimate its scalability versus limits, particularly CPU and Heap Size. It's optimized on queries & dmls and won't exceed the daily single email limit but could run to several thousand in a transaction. What's the best tool and method for estimating how it will perform at higher scales?

Note that we are refactoring it with batching, but until that's ready, I need to advise stakeholders on how many we can safely send.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to time it a few times and see what the CPU time and heap looks like. I've successfully [sent 10,000 emails in a single call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/137204/2984), but your mileage will vary, depending on the complexity of the email and if you're using a template or not (a template greatly reduces heap use, but may incur SOQL costs). I think the reasonable limit per call is probably 1k-10k for most typical scripts I've written.

Comment: I was also trying to track down any documentation about limits on external emails that you and @adrianlarson were talking about in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/137204/761 but I couldn't find any current references to those limits.

Comment: @AlwaysThinkin [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334302&type=1&mode=1) is probably what you're looking for.